# URL in JSP always goes to localhost and gives HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, http, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm using a servlet to generate an html page, and in the java I code the URL to output a standard href and it seems to output fine on the page, however when I click on it, I get HTTP Status 404.

In my servlet the code is :-

```
    out.write("<html>");
    out.write("<body>");
    out.write("<br/>");
    out.write("<a href=\"url\"" + "facebook.com" + "\">" + "facebook.com"
            + "</a>" + "<br/>");
            out.write("</body");
    out.write("</html>");
```

And it looks fine in the generated html page when I view source.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <br/>
    <a href="url"facebook.com">facebook.com</a>
    <br/> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

However everytime I click it the link appears as .http://localhost:8080/MyProject/url  and of course this goes to HTTP Status 404 - /MyProject/url.

Anything I can do to get it to actually go to a URL, i.e. facebook.com

I'm using Tomcat 7 as my app server.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: the generated HTML does not look "fine" at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it

```
out.write("<a href='facebook.com'>facebook.com</a> <br/>");
```

Generating view from servlet is bad idea, use JSTL instead

Comment: Thanks very much, I got to the answer you posted just now, always helps to have another pair of eyes, and yes I will be exploring JSTL tomorrow.